# Error occurred when removing the user in EpiServer - ArgumentNullException: The type cannot be null

Tags: episerver, episerver-relate+

I have used,

```
CommunitySystem.CurrentContext.DefaultSecurity.RemoveUser(IUser user);
```

To remove user (Just as the answer posted in [this issue](https://world.episerver.com/forum/legacy-forums/Episerver-Community/Thread-Container/2013/11/Find-and-delete-inactive-users/)).

However, this works fine. But for one user it gives an error. The exception throws from the `RemoveUser(IUser user)`.

The exception details are here as below,

```
System.ArgumentNullException: The type cannot be null. Parameter name: type 
at EPiServer.Data.Entity.Internal.EntityTypeResolver.GetTypeName(Type type, Boolean ignoreOverrideAttribute) 
at EPiServer.Common.ImplementationModule.HandleCommentAddUpdateRemove(IComment comment, SupportedOperations operation) 
at EPiServer.Common.Comments.CommentHandler.OnCommentUpdated(IComment comment) 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Common.Comments.CommentHandler.UpdateComment(IComment comment) 
at EPiServer.Common.Data.FrameworkFactoryBase.CascadeUpdateStatus(IEntityStatus entity, ICollection`1 children) 
at EPiServer.Common.Data.CommentFactory.CascadeAuthorStatus(IAuthor author) 
at EPiServer.Common.AuthorEventHandler.Invoke(EntityEventArgs args) 
at EPiServer.Common.AuthorHandler.OnAuthorUpdated(IAuthor author) 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Common.AuthorHandler.UpdateAuthor(IAuthor author) 
at EPiServer.Common.Data.FrameworkFactoryBase.CascadeUpdateStatus(IEntityStatus entity, ICollection`1 children) 
at EPiServer.Common.Security.Data.SecurityFactory.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.Internal.SqlDatabaseExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1.b__0() 
at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlTransientErrorsRetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 method) 
at EPiServer.Common.Security.SecurityHandler.RemoveUser(IUser user)
```

I have tried to extract the `Type` and Type Name and it worked fine.

```
IUser user = getUser(id);
Type type = user.AccessRightsType;
string typeName = new EPiServer.Data.Entity.Internal.EntityTypeResolver().GetTypeName(type, true); // Not null. This value is as same as on other users
```

Update: I have decompiled the `EPiServer.Common.ImplementationModule` and this is what the `HandleCommentAddUpdateRemove(..)` has.

```
private static void HandleCommentAddUpdateRemove(IComment comment, SupportedOperations operation) {
    EntityReference commentedEntity = comment.CommentedEntity;
    IComment comment2 = null;
    CommentEventData commentEventData;
    if ((int) operation == 4) {
        comment2 = (IComment) comment.get_Master();
        if (comment2 == null || comment2.Status == comment.Status) {
            return;
        }
        commentedEntity = comment2.CommentedEntity;
        commentEventData = new CommentEventData(IEntityTypeResolverExtensions.GetTypeName(ServiceLocator.get_Current().GetInstance < IEntityTypeResolver > (), commentedEntity.get_Type()), commentedEntity.get_ID(), comment2.Status, -1);
        m_commentEvent.Raise(m_commentId, (object) commentEventData);
    }
    commentEventData = new CommentEventData(IEntityTypeResolverExtensions.GetTypeName(ServiceLocator.get_Current().GetInstance < IEntityTypeResolver > (), commentedEntity.get_Type()), commentedEntity.get_ID(), comment.Status, ((int) operation != 8) ? 1 : (-1));
    m_commentEvent.Raise(m_commentId, (object) commentEventData);
}
```

What causes this to happen ?

It seems like the below code returns 'Null'

`commentedEntity.get_Type();`

Any way to delete this user?

*Additional info:*

```
EPiServer.CommonFramework version=9.0.1
EPiServer.CMS.Core version=11.11.0
EPiServer.Community version=9.0.0
```

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with it trying to remove the user's comments (`HandleCommentAddUpdateRemove`) which in turn invokes `GetTypeName`, but I haven't worked with Community at all. Regardless, you might be better off posting questions on Community on world.episerver.com.

Comment: @TedNyberg Thanks. Posted the issue in [Episerver developer forums](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/Problems-and-bugs/Thread-Container/2019/5/error-occurred-when-removing-the-user-in-episerver---argumentnullexception-the-type-cannot-be-null/)